# Row wise validation Inline jqgrid

Tags: jquery, validation, jqgrid

In my application I am using JqGrid in inline edit mode but I am facing the issue how to row wise validate JqGrid.

In my JqGrid having start date and close date in first and second column respectively, validation must be like.

1. Close date always greater than start date in same row.
2. In row wise validation in second row start date must be greater than close date of previous row.

Related to that seanario if suggession please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution to your problem. Use the event **beforeSaveRow** to make sure data is valid.
Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adgptkvj/207/) link if you want to play with it.

```
 <table id="list"></table>
 <div id="pager"></div>

$('#list').jqGrid("getRowData",rowid);

                var val1 = jQuery('#' + rowid + '_' + 'date1').val();        
                  var val2 = jQuery('#' + rowid + '_' + 'date2').val(); 

                 var date1=new Date(val1);
                 var date2=new Date(val2);
                 if(date1>date2)
                 {
                   alert('please enter correct date from current row');
                    return false;
                 }


                  var currenttr = $("#"+rowid).closest('tr');
                 var prevtr = currenttr.prev();
                 var prevId= prevtr.attr("id");
                 // row is not first
                 if(prevId)
                 {
                     var previousRow=  $('#list').jqGrid("getRowData",prevId);  

                    var closedate=new Date(previousRow.date2);
                   if(date1 < closedate)
                    {
                      alert('please enter correct date from previous row');
                        return false;
                    }
                 }
                   return true;

                },
            });
            }

            });
```

Comment: @Anuja did you try the solution. Please add comments on what you did so others can benefit.